# Flutter Catcher module does not give full stack

Tags: flutter, exception

The Android App crashes on few user mobiles, I am unable to reproduce with AVD or physical mobile.

Play console shows few platformExceptions in recent time

Following are from Playconsole.

**Context.startForegroundService() did not then call Service.startForeground(): Serv
java.lang.IllegalStateException

com.github.florent37.assets_audio_player.playerimplem.PlayerImplemMediaPlayer.stop
android.app.RemoteServiceException

android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage**

The catcher module catched but the error got through email does not have enough information.

*Error:
PlatformException(WRONG_FORMAT, The specified argument must be an Map containing a `path`, null)
Stack trace:
Device parameters:
...*

The stack trace used to show source code line but it is blank now.
I am using latest catcher.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try to increase the logger buffer from your device developer option.The bigger buffer size will help you to see the full catcher.